# A directory path result in FILE_IS_NOT_DIRECTORY error

Tags: mule4, mule-connector

I get below error when using file connector to write a file to a working directory (Windows host).

The File connector version is v1.3.4 and mulesoft runtime is 4.3.0

```
ERROR 2021-07-05 02:13:56,335 [[MuleRuntime].uber.125059: [my-process].inventory-snapshot-file-observer.CPU_LITE @1ee1dd59] [event: 238918e0-dd58-11eb-9534-0050569e1eb4] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
Error type: FILE:CONNECTIVITY
Error.description: ->Provided workingDir '\\HOST\SCDR-QA$\In' is not a directory<-
```

However, when I copy the workingDir above and paste into Windows, it can be opened without any issue.

Please share any idea if any, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. `'\\HOST\SCDR-QA$\In' is not a directory` means that `\\host\...` is not a path mounted in the local host. It is a format called UNC which is used by Windows to access files remotely via a network protocol, usually the SMB protocol. The File connector can only [open files in the same server or host](https://docs.mulesoft.com/file-connector/1.3/), not over network protocols:

> Anypoint Connector for File (File Connector) handles files and folders
> on a locally mounted file system.

You can mount the remote path locally using Windows commands so applications can access the remote files with local file operations. You can also try to find an alternative connector for the SMB protocol. There is no official one from MuleSoft. Another alternative could be to develop your own SMB connector, though it probably would take a significant effort.